# Error while creating xml rss feed from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I get the following error when I'm making an XML RSS Feed from a MySQL database on localhost:

`Extra content at the end of the document`

Here's my code:

```
     <?php
// PDO connect *********
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lookout', 'admin', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}

$pdo = connect();

// posts *******************************
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `event` ORDER BY serial DESC';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rs_post = $query->fetchAll();

// The XML structure

$data .= '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">';
$data .= '<channel>';

foreach ($rs_post as $row) {
    $data .= '<item>';
    $data .= '<time>'.$row['timestamp'].'</time>';
    $data .= '<date>'.$row['timestamp'].'</date>';
    $data .= '<location>'.$row['longitude'].'</location>';
    $data .= '<report>'.$row['details'].'</report>';
    $data .= '</item>';
}
$data .= '</channel>';
$data .= '</rss> ';

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo $data;
?>
```

There are no root tags missing, everything seems to be in order but obviously isn't.

Comment: If you'd include a generated example it might help. Couldn't it be that something coming from the db messes up the output? An unescaped `<` or `>` maybe?

Comment: Easiest to get started with debugging this should be to check the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

> As per @fejese's comment, this is likely due to unescaped content in your database. Instead of building up the document using strings by hand, why not use an established library like DomDocument to create the elements in a safe way?

Here's an example of using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to build up the RSS Xml Feed, instead of doing this manually from string concatenation. This way, all the heavy lifting of escaping invalid character sequences which may be present in your database are done by the library:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$element = $xml->createElement('rss');

$rss = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement("rss"));
$rss->setAttribute("version","2.0");
$rss->setAttribute("xmlns:atom","http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
$channel = $xml->createElement("channel");
foreach ($rs_post as $row) {
    $item = $xml->createElement("item");
    $item->appendChild($xml->createElement("time", $row['timestamp']));
    $item->appendChild($xml->createElement("date", $row['timestamp']));
    $item->appendChild($xml->createElement("location", $row['longitude']));
    $item->appendChild($xml->createElement("report", $row['details']));
    $channel->appendChild($item);
}
$rss->appendChild($channel);

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: Hey your answer is productive and helpful but this wasn't the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

It was an append on $data that was causing the problem.

A `$data = "";` before first using `$data` removed the error.

Going into the source code of the xml document that was displaying the error gave a better and more detailed error and said something along the lines of `Variable doesn't exist: data`.

**Edit:**

What Stuart says in another answer could also cause the same problem and he makes an interesting point of creating an XML RSS feed another way using a DOM library.